# Can a guid be a good partition key?

Tags: c#, scalability, guid, scale, partitioning

I have to store many gigabytes of data across multiple machines. The files are uniquely identified by Guid and one file can be hosted on one machine only. I was wondering if I could use the Guid as a partition key to determine which machine should I use to store the data. If so, what would be my partition function?

Otherwise, how could I partition my data in such way that all the machine get a very similar load?

Thanks!

P.S. I am not using Sql Server, Oracle or any other DB. This is all in-house code.
P.S.S. The Guid are generated using the .NET function Guid.NewGuid().

Comment: Doesn't this depend on how the Guids are generated? Are they random - or can you control the generation?  If you can control it you can ensure it's a good partition key.  If it's random it would depend on the properties of the generation algorithm.

Comment: Good point. The Guids are generated by .NET using Guid.NewGuid().

Comment: I don't understand. Your data is stored "across multiple machines", but "can be hosted on one machine only"? The rest sounds far too specific for anyone who doesn't know your program to be able to answer.

Comment: Are they generated by one process/thread on one machine?  In any case you can always just overwrite some bytes manually to ensure you get a good distribution.  Or just use a hashing method.

Comment: No, they are generated by many processes on different machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As James said in his comment, you need something that has a good, uniform distribution.  Guids do not have this property.  I would recommend a hash, even one as simple as a hash of the Guid itself.

A SHA-1 hash has a good distribution.  I wouldn't recommend even/odd hashing unless you plan on only distributing between 2 machines.

Answer (score 0):

Because GUIDs are random you could distribute them by storing the odd GUIDs on one machine and the even GUIDs on the other...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tests = new List<Guid>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        tests.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Even: " + tests.Where(g => g.ToByteArray().Last() % 2 == 0).Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Odd : " + tests.Where(g => g.ToByteArray().Last() % 2 == 1).Count());
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Gives a near equal distribution.

**EDIT**

Indeed this will not work when splitting across more than 2 machines although you could then split again on an other byte being odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round robin your distribution I would be looking at the possibility of a synchronized counter which you % the number of machines you have in a classical round robin manner.

The synchronized counter could be a field in a database, it could be a single web service, or a file on the network etc. Anything which could be incremented every time a file gets placed.

Comment: How then, would you go about finding the data after you've placed it?

Comment: @Kyle W Sorry, I thought he just wanted a partition balancer, you would need to store the retrieval key somewhere along with the rest of the info about the file.